# Numpy ValueError: no fill-function for data-type

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I know it doesn't make sense, but I executed the command:

```
numpy.arange(0, 5, 1, numpy.bool_)
```

And it returned an error `ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.`. All data types seems to be working except boolean which return this error.

I was expecting `False, True, True, True, True`, what causes that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing

```
numpy.arange(0, 2, 1, numpy.bool_)
```

Works fine, becuase `np.bool_` type is still meaningful for range [0,2).
However, what is the meaning of range [0,5) for type `bool_`??
This is the error you get - numpy tries to tell you that you are asking for values in invalid range.

Comment: I was under the impression that any non zero number is True in python, isn't that the case?