# Numpy.fromfunction(): How to use it with strings?

Tags: python, numpy

The first line works, but the second doesn't:

```
print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y:     10 * x + y , (3, 5), dtype=int))
print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: str(10 * x + y), (3, 5), dtype=str))

[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/cygdrive/c/Users/pafh2/OneDrive/dev/reverb/t.py", line 439, in <module>
    print(np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: str(10 * x + y), (3, 5), dtype=str))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 2027, in fromfunction
    args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1968, in indices
    res[i] = arange(dim, dtype=dtype).reshape(
ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
>>>
```

Which page of the Numpy documentation explains the difference?

StackOverflow won't let me post, telling me, "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So now everyone has to read this pointless paragraph I've just added.

Now it says I've still not written enough "details", though I really have, so here's more added spam to appease the the StackOverflow spam-filter "A.I.".

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what the `dtype` is supposed to be doing in `fromfunction`?  Reread the docs.

This action is producing the same error:

```
In [2]: np.arange(3, dtype=str)                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9944cc5541d5> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange(3, dtype=str)

ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

You may be confused about what `fromfunction` does.  It generates arrays with `np.indices`, and passes them **whole** the function.  It does not iterate or pass values one by one.  It is **not** `np.frompyfunc`.

```
In [4]: np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: str(10 * x + y), (3, 5))                                          
Out[4]: '[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]\n [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.]\n [20. 21. 22. 23. 24.]]'

In [5]: np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: str(10 * x + y), (3, 5), dtype=int)                               
Out[5]: '[[ 0  1  2  3  4]\n [10 11 12 13 14]\n [20 21 22 23 24]]'
```

`Out[4]` is float, `Out[5]` is int.  The `dtype` sets the dtype of `indices`, which propagates through the function.  The `str` in the lambda turns the `10*x+y` array into a string.

`fromfunction` isn't very useful.  You can get the same results with:

```
In [6]: 10*np.arange(3)[:,None] + np.arange(5)                                                         
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

====

The code for `fromfunction` is simple:

```
args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
return function(*args, **kwargs)
```

all it is doing creating the `indices` and passing them to the function.

```
In [10]: np.indices((3,5))                                                                             
Out[10]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])

In [12]: np.mgrid[:3, :5]       # alternatives                                                                       
Out[12]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]])
In [15]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(5), indexing='ij')                                        
Out[15]: 
[array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]), array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I see I was misusing dtype.

Comment: I have to agree with OP here though, `numpy`'s [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) of `fromfunction` is pretty missleading if at least confusing. `numpy.indices` is mentioned in the 'see also', but it is not clear at all how they are related, unless you are familiar with them I guess. I was curious why OP's approach didn't work, so I did my own little research. Maybe you could comment on that? Otherwise I might make it its own question.

Answer (score 0):

This has not directly to do with `numpy.fromfunction`. If you look at the traceback you posted, you can see that the problem originates from this line:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1968, in indices
    res[i] = arange(dim, dtype=dtype).reshape(
```

If you look at the file, you will find that `arange` is nothing else than `numpy.arange`. So you can do the following test which will result in the same `ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.`:

```
import numpy as np


a = np.arange(0, 10, dtype=str)
```

So what does that tell us? A qick internet search for the error message returns [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45478718/5472354)

> Executing `numpy.arange(0, 2, 1, numpy.bool_)` works fine, because `np.bool_` type is still meaningful for range [0,2). However, what is the meaning of range [0,5) for type `bool_`??
>   This is the error you get - numpy tries to tell you that you are asking for values in invalid range.

Here is where it gets interesting: if we apply that logic to the `str` dtype, what would be a valid range? Let's try the example from the post:

```
numpy.arange(0, 2, 1, str)
# >>> ['0' '1']
```

This works, so the range and step size seem to satisfy dtype `str`. What happens if we increase the range?

```
numpy.arange(0, 3, 1, str)
# >>> ValueError: no fill-function for data-type.
```

We get the error from before. Why is that? I have no idea. But this is where the root of your problem lies.

Comment: Usually we want integers from `np.arange`.  Sometimes floats (though `linspace` is usually better).  It also works with `np.datetime64` dtypes.  I've never seen it used with `str`, and don't know what to expect.   It's compiled so we can't dig into its guts.  `np.arange('a','z')` might make sense, but it tells me it can't subtract strings (which makes sense).

Comment: Thanks for your insight! I always wondered what it means when the source code is just a blank definition. If anything, I am even more intrigued now though.